# Multiple Use of validations in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation

I have an API with validation on it.

```
public class ModelVo {

    @NotBlank(message = "...")
    private String name;

    @Pattern(regex="...", message = "...")
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

I use of it

```
@PostMapping("/path1")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Object>> create(@Valid @RequestBody ModelVo modelvo){
```

Now I want use of this validation for other method( for instance update API) again but I don't like @Pattern annotation on lastName fild work for second method. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean that for `create()` you want to validate `lastName` with `@Pattern` but for `update()` you don't want to validate `lastName` or you want to validate it in any other way? This is it?

Comment: Yes, for update() I don't want to validate lastName.  @João Dias

Comment: Then check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for `create()` you want to validate `lastName` with `@Pattern` but for `update()` you don't want to validate `lastName` you can achieve this with validation groups.

Your Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/path1")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Object>> create(@Validated @RequestBody 
ModelVo modelvo){

@PutMapping("/path1")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<Object>> update(@Validated(BasicInfo.class) @RequestBody 
ModelVo modelvo){
```

Your Model class:

```
public class ModelVo {

   @NotBlank(message = "...", groups = BasicInfo.class)
   private String name;

   @Pattern(regex="...", message = "...")
   private String lastName;
}
```

You also need to create the `BasicInfo` class but that has nothing special.

You may get more information from the following links:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html